# Open app directly from filter email notifications

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, email-notification, tag-filters

I have a Stack Exchange-wide [filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) set up to email me every few hours when certain tags are used. However, when clicking the links in the email, they always open in Safari, from which I need to click the "read in app" link.

Can we get these links to [open the Stack Exchange app directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462612/link-to-automatically-open-my-app), if it's installed?